# Add Facebook poll over Graph API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know if it's possible to add one of the new Facebook "Question" polls through the Graph API? If so, how?

I did my best to Google and check through the documentation but failed rather hard -- Googling "Facebook question API" clearly is a terrible idea.

I didn't see it in the documentation but I know the docs sometimes lag behind actual functionality. Also, I could easily have missed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since questions themselves are out of date, creating a question via the Graph API is now [deprecated](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/question) and no longer supported.

Comment: This is WAY outdated and at this point the API  no longer offers this functionality - not sure WHY my answer below is getting downvoted - WTF is going on with this site?

Comment: @DropHit I think you got downvoted because you had two answers that were mostly the same (one of them is now deleted). But you're right, this answer was out of date, so I updated it with 2017 information.

Comment: Soooo your answer is different than mine below?

Answer (score 4):

You can now write questions to the Graph API by issuing an HTTP POST to https://graph.facebook.com/PROFILE_ID/questions with the question content.

For example:

```
curl -F 'access_token=...' \
     -F 'question=What is your favorite color?' \
     https://graph.facebook.com/me/questions
```

Full how-to here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/635/

Answer (score 2):

Facebook Questions are able to be [read by the graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/590/).

Update: they also just [announced](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/635/) that you can now create them via the API as well.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - This has been deprecated as of Graph 1.0 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/question