# post facebook QuestionObject through graph api / php sdk

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add Facebook “Question” over Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687221/add-facebook-question-over-graph-api)

I was looking in graph API of facebook, there I only find about reading the information related to a question or all questions. see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/question/

But I can't find any help regarding posting a question to wall. Please guide me if there is any way of doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687221/add-facebook-question-over-graph-api/7936995#7936995

Answer (score 0):

Till now facebook doesn't allow to post question using graph.You can read questions from facebook.see this tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/590/

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no possibilities for application to publish Questions and Question Options via Graph API. Only "white-listed" application allowed to do so (which means you need a special agreement with Facebook on that)

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there any way of posting question using php/javascript sdk?

Comment: No, not possible.  Questions are currently read-only via the public APIs that facebook has allowed us to use.