# Is it possible to connect the like button to a poll

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, facebook-social-plugins

I hope I do not ask the wrong question here, it is not a specific programming question. Anyway I would like to know if there is a way for people to click the like button on a website and send that to a facebook poll as one of the options in that poll instead of a page.

Example

There is a competition in my poll I want people to vote for either team 1, 2 or 3. On my website I present those 3 teams with some text and a seperate like-button. when clicked on I want depending which button is pressed to send +1 to 1 of the teams in that poll.

I hope I made my question understandable.

Regards Niels

Answer (score 0):

You can link the `href` attributes of your like-buttons to different targets, e.g. `href="<url>/team1"`. This way you can put multiple like-buttons on one site but they get different counters (you like *different things*).

Note that the site you're linking to has to exist on your server and should have the `OG-Tags` defined. Especially `og:title` and `og:url` should differ from each other.
See http://ogp.me/

If you're talking about the questions-API and posting answers to a question on Facebook, I don't think that's possible. You can post questions though: [Add Facebook poll over Graph API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687221/add-facebook-question-over-graph-api/8949689#8949689)

---

Example for your team presentation page.
Note that you can change `team1` to a parameter like `?team=1` as well.

```
Team 1 is the best team!
Like it here: <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.com/team1" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>

But Team 2 was last years winner
Like it here: <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.com/team2" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>

and Team 3 rocks everything!
Like it here: <div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.example.com/team3" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

You should make a script that dynamically displays your team and different `og-tags` on the site you're linking to, e.g. for `team=1` you get the `og:title = Team 1` and so on

Comment: Thank you for such a fast awnser. Most of what you tell me I understand. I make a link to 1 page with defferent targets, in this example the teams. Is there a example on the web that you know of? And how does that connection work, how do I present more teams on 1 page? Regards Niels

Comment: I understand what you say here, but I don't understand how the 'vote' for one of the teams on my team page gets to my poll 'which team do you like best?' team 1, 2, 3 I click team 1 - and then it must sent +1 to a facebook page which has those teams presented there, facebook will be the gathering point for all votes and I would like that in 1 poll which has those teams in it. Sorry if I misunderstand, I'm not familiar with facebook programming so I appreciate all the help. Regards Niels

Comment: You can link to a Facebook Page as well, I think the counters should get combined if you click either of them.

Comment: I know but in that case I will have to make as much facebook pages as there are teams, because if I make 1 page all of the Votes get mixed up in 1 total, then I can't see which of the teams has won. ~ read on ~

Comment: Thats why I want 1 page with 1 poll and put the teams in the poll. Then let people like 1 of the teams on my webpage, the like button on my webpage then sends +1 to one of the awnsers in the poll, in this case team 1. so to be precise: webpage - click like on on of the teams presented - +1 gets in my poll on the chosen team on Fcaebook. If i don't make sense please tell me, and if I need to stop ask questions tell me as well. Regards Niels

Answer (score 0):

If you do implement this, you might be in violation of Facebook Policy.

http://developers.facebook.com/policy/

https://www.facebook.com/page_guidelines.php#promotionsguidelines

> v.    You must not use Facebook features or functionality, such as the
>   Like button, as a voting mechanism for a promotion.